# ㄹ 수(가) 있다/없다 Problems in the addition of 가

Tags: grammar

I know that it definitely makes sense to add 가 here because 수 is indeed a pseudo-noun. However will there be any differences between adding 가 and not adding? It would seem that they are the same thing, because I heard them equally frequently used.

Comment: can you explain why  수 is a pseudo-noun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different. But the difference is subtle and I can't find the general rule right now. Let me instead show you some examples. I never studied Korean professionally, so the following is based on my experience.

When we want to express will, we remove 가.

> - 우리는 할 수 있어.
>
>   We can do it.
> - 이 경기는 질 수 없어.
>
>   I can't lose this game. (I really want to win this game.)

When we want to express complaint or assert something, we put 가.

> - 모기 때문에 잠을 잘 수가 없다.
>
>   I can't sleep because of mosquitos.
> - 이 경기는 질 수가 없어.
>
>   I can't lose this game. (There is no way that I can lose this game.)

In my opinion, it's better to remove 가 because it sounds more neutral, but they seem to be almost the same in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon there are some different nuiance between each and I will show you additional cases.

> 수가 있다. There is/are a/some way (for specific purpose given by the context)

```
       (Korean usually don't concern about articles.)
```

> 이길 수 있다.      We can win.
>
> 이길 수 없다.      We cannot win.

I'm afraid to explain them above like this. (Maybe some korean don't agree with me.)
But I would say only these sentences give more stress on the verb to win, in contrast, the others do so on the 'way'(수).

> 이길 수가 있다.     There is a way to win.
>
> 이길 수가 없다.     There is no way to win.
>
> 이길 수도 있다.     There is a less certain way to win.
>
> 비길 수도 없다.     There is no way even to draw.

For the meaning of 'even', using to win instead of to draw doesn't make sense semantically.

> 이길 수는 있다.     There is a certain/some way to win.
>
> 이길 수는 없다.     There is not a way to win.

As shown above, each structure of -수가, -수도 and -수는 is to mean slightly different nuiance.

Answer (score -1):

I think they are the same...

Although I can't explain it, 가 is used more commonly in sentences such as 나는 잘 수가 없어 (I cannot sleep).
But sentences such as 나는 이거를 할수 있어 does not use 가 as often.
I think it's that verbs that require 를 afterwards do not use 가, as verbs that do not require it use 수.

Sorry, I only know what sounds correct in my head. :(

Source: My mom is from Korea and only speaks in Korean to me.

Comment: Just a quick addition, I just realized 가 sounds a lot better flowed with 없어 and very awkward with 있어. So my previous answer has derived to that 가 is paired with 없어 and not 있어.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Are you able to edit your previous answer to add this information?